# Chrome rendering issue

Tags: google-chrome

I noticed that a lot of pages are not fully rendered. I experience it a lot on my Ubuntu 18.04, but I just found the same issue on 16.04.

Like in the picture:

[image: Broken picture]

What's more as I zoom out, the content is gradually adding up. See here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that [Chrome Screen Shader plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-shader-smart-scree/fmlboobidmkelggdainpknloccojpppi?hl=en) caused the problem on Ubuntu 16.04. I will need some time to confirm if there was the same root cause  for Ubuntu 18.04.